# Two dimensional array gives index out of range error in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a two dimensional array of "Team" object and have one array of "Team" when I try to print appended array from 2d array, It gives error. In below code print gives error.

```
self.first_array = []
    for i in 0..<json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"].count {
        guard let name = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["name"].string,
            let id = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["id"].int,
            let teamId = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["TeamID"].int,
            let points = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["points"].string,
            let played = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["played"].string,
            let wins = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["wins"].string,
            let draws = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["draws"].string,
            let defeits = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["defeits"].string,
            let goalsfor = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["goalsfor"].string,
            let goalsagainst = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["goalsagainst"].string,
            let average = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["average"].int,
            let rank = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["rank"].int,
            let hasTeamLogo = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["HasTeamLogo"].bool,
            let imageUrl = json["LeagueStage"][0]["LeagueTable"][i]["TeamLogo"].string
            else {
                let dataFetch: [AnyHashable : Any] =
                    [
                        NSLocalizedDescriptionKey :  NSLocalizedString("Veri Yok", value: "Hata", comment: "") ,
                        NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey : NSLocalizedString("Veri Yok", value: "Hata", comment: "")            ]
                let err = NSError(domain: "ShiploopHttpResponseErrorDomain", code: 401, userInfo: dataFetch)
                self.delegate?.errorUpdating(err as NSError)
                return
        }
        let temp_team = Team(id: id,
                             teamId: teamId,
                             name: name,
                             points: Int(points)!,
                             played: Int(played)!,
                             wins: Int(wins)!,
                             draws: Int(draws)!,
                             defeits: Int(defeits)!,
                             goalsfor: Int(goalsfor)!,
                             goalsagainst: Int(goalsagainst)!,
                             average: average,
                             rank: rank,
                             HasTeamLogo: hasTeamLogo,
                             imageurl: imageUrl
        )
            self.first_array.append(temp_team)
    }
}
    self.teams.append(first_array)
    print(teams[0][0].name)
```

Initialize Part

```
// MARK: - Variables
var teams = [[Team]]()
var first_array = [Team]()
```

I'm sure there is no problem with first_array because when I do like below, It works.

```
self.teams = [self.first_array, self.first_array]
```

Error:

> fatal error: Index out of range

and I can print it with

```
print(self.teams.popLast()?[0].name)
```

Comment: What is the error log says exactly ?

Comment: @Tushar fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: Swift convention is to use lowerCamelCase names for variables, instead of snake_case. Also, you should prefer `let` constants and array literals over `var` variables and `append` calls.

Comment: It probably goes to the else condition and not adding the team object to the array. Means, the JSON data might not have a name in the `LeagueTable` entry.

Comment: @eonr what is teams count?

Comment: @Tushar No it is adding it because I can print first_array[0] for example

Comment: @TusharSharma Actually It is correct and "2"

Comment: I can print it with .popLast() function just [0][0] is not working. However, I don't understand why?

Comment: @eonr what is this ? self.first_array = []

Comment: The code in a function so when I call function again, It delete all the data from before calling.

Comment: @eonr instead just do teams.removeAll() in viewDidAppear and call your api function after that.

Answer (score 0):

`self.first_array` and `first_array` are referring to different things.

Comment: You should really take a look at using Codable from Swift 4 to alleviate you from writing all this crazy json code.

Comment: Well... upgrade. Swift 3 won't be supported for long

Answer (score 0):

If the above code is correct, then the problem is `self.teams` is not same same as local variable `var teams = [[Team]]()`. Same with `self.first_array` and local var `first_array`. Hope you got the point.

To fix the problem, do either of the following:

instead of writing 
`var teams = [[Team]]()
var first_array = [Team]()`

write

`self.teams = [[Team]]()
self.first_array = [Team]()`

or,

instead of `self.teams.append(self.first_array)`, write `teams.append(first_array)` and then `self.teams = teams`

Answer (score -1):

I was calling below code where call function in question.

```
 self.teams = [[]]
```

I change it to this and It is working now.

```
self.teams = [[],[]]
```